# What is the difference between bounded generic type and just parent type?

Tags: java, generics

Could anybody explain what would be the difference in using the following methods:

```
<T extends Object> void method(T input){
}
```

and just

```
void method(Object input){
}
```

As far as I understand - in both cases we have Object type in runtime.
What is the benefit of using bounded generic?

Comment: I think in your case nothing is different.  If `T` were used elsewhere there would be something, but as-is it's equivalent.  (There might be some very very subtle language differences, but I don't know what they are.  In every practical and important way, it's exactly the same.)

Comment: I'll add that using the second declaration imo is better.  It's less complicated and does the same thing, so by KISS it's better.

Comment: The same is true of `method(Object input)`, it is also captured as an `Integer` at run time.  What I said is true: they are the same.

Comment: Whoops, just because method return type is `void`... Yet a good codding style would suggest using the former.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you assume there is a benefit? The first is just a more verbose form of the second one, like 1+1+1+1+1 is a more verbose way of expressing 5.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference the way you have it.

But, the construct `T extends Object` is used in context of some other "feature". I am *forced* to use it when I refactor some code, at times. Imagine this method (yes, we had code like this in production at some point in time):

```
public static <T> int sizeOfList(T obj) {
    if (obj instanceof List) {
        return ((List) obj).size();
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("only list is supported");
}
```

It's bad. I can just move the *runtime* check to a *compile* time check, so naively you can do:

```
public static <T extends List<?>> int sizeOfList(T obj) {
    return obj.size();
}
```

There is a subtle problem here though. The *erasure* of `T` in the first method is `Object`, the erasure in the second method is `List`. So now same callers (if they do not recompile) are in for a nasty surprise called :  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.

To get away from that (and people hating me after I refactor), I do:

```
public static <T extends Object & List<?>> int sizeOfList(T obj) {
    return obj.size();
}
```

The compile time safety is still there, but the erasure is now on the first bound : `Object`, same as it was before.

Comment: Instead, `public static <T extends Collection<?>> int sizeOf(T obj) { return obj.size(); }` could be used. A rule on thumb is that `extends` and `Object` do not fit together. Whenever you have to be explicit use either *wildcard* (`?`) or a generic type rather than the generalization `Object`.

Comment: @dbl right, `List<?>` was provided just as an example (to match that inner `instanceof`). As you can see in the answer, though _extremely rare_, using `? extends Object & ...` does make sense.

Comment: `<T extends Object & List<?>>`  is the verbose form of `<T extends List<?>>`, as any type (even T) extends Object by default. Actually `?` substitute `Object` in this very same example.

Comment: @dbl what are the _erasures_ of the examples of yours above?

Comment: 1) `Object & List`, 2) `List`

Comment: @dbl wrong. 1) `Object` 2) `List`. read the JLS a bit and then come back to this discussion please.

Comment: Now I've assimilated your answer and I see that `... extends Object & Collection<?>` is actually needed in such cases. And about the discussion we've started I guess what you mean is that the type is being erased to Object, while `((List)obj)::method` is being applied as a usage.